# Separating repository and implementation in Spring-Data

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

Given some abstract entity:

```
public interface Person{

    long getID();

    String getFirstName();

    String getLastName();
}
```

And repository to work with this entity:

```
public interface PersonRepository {

    void save(Person person);

    Person findOne(long id);

}
```

I want to implement above repository with different technologies: MongoDB with Spring Data MongoDB, Jpa with Spring Data JPA and for example Cassandra with my own implementation of repository. Can somebody point me on documentation about implementing own Spring Data module?

How can I use Spring Data concepts to use both existed solutions and create my own implementation? 
It will be great if you can provide simple example.

Answer (score 2):

There's already a [module for Cassandra](https://github.com/SciSpike/spring-data-cassandra) in the making, so I suggest to contact the maintainers and help out if you like to. Other than that, most of the community driven modules have started by simply studying the existing modules and working their way backwards.